# js dynamically access private fields (properties/members)

Tags: javascript, private, private-members, class-fields

I'm trying out the new [class private member feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_fields)  However, I've quickly run into a problem: How does one dynamically access them?

I expected it to follow pre-existing syntax of either

```
constructor(prop, val) {
  this[`#${prop}`] = val; // undefined
}
```

or

```
constructor(prop, val) {
  this.#[prop] = val; // syntax error
}
```

However, both of the above fail.

Comment: have you tried creating the property first and setting it?

Comment: Yes, my actual pre-declares them as empty objects. If I manually enumerate them all in the constructor and set them to the vals, that works fine (albeit very tedious and brittle), but then the catch-all get and set have the same problem—which defeats their purpose, so there must be a way to do this dynamically (otherwise the JS authors made a huge oversight).

Comment: `this[\`#${prop}\`]` would just set a normal property as there would be no way of telling if it was meant as private or a regular legitimate property name containing a `#`. As for `#[prop]` in the [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/README.md#private-syntax) that is said to be a syntax error as there is no computed prop names for them. So a dynamic access may not be available in the current stage

Comment: Ugh, I hope not as that would be a prohibitive/preclusive limitation. The MDN documentation suggests that the `#` is simply part of the name, so based on that, I would expect concatenation to work just fine 

Comment: simply you cant!

Comment: @jacob I guess you would have to implement a module pattern

Comment: If you could do this, then you could also access the property from outside the class using the same method.

Comment: @Barmar that's not true

Comment: @AngelSalazar my workaround is to have constructor return a `Proxy`

Comment: @jacob check adriancg answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think you can access private fields dynamically. The [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/README.md#private-syntax) says:

> There are no private computed property names: `#foo` is a private identifier, and `#[foo]` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to have a private object for the keys you want to access dynamically:

```
class privateTest {
  #pvt = {}

  constructor(privateKey, privateVal) {
    this.#pvt[privateKey] = privateVal;
  }

  getPrivate(privateKey) {
    return this.#pvt[privateKey];
  }

}

const test = new privateTest('hello', 'world');
console.log(test.getPrivate('hello')) // world
```

Answer (score 5):

If you reaaaaally wanted to do it.

```
eval(`this.#${propertyName}`)
```

But that's just opening a very ugly can of worms.

Comment: So in order to achieve that you'll have to turn to the dark side.

Answer (score 3):

From the FAQ on the proposal for private properties:

> Dynamic access to private fields is contrary to the notion of 'private'.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-thisx-access-the-private-field-named-x-given-that-thisx-does

The lack of dynamic access to private fields is by design.

Comment: Though in OP's case (and my case why I'm searching for this), he wants to dynamically access the private field within the private scope. Everything stays private. For me, I have a bunch of variables holding private callback functions and would love to have a string array of method names I can dynamically access.

Comment: `Dynamic access to private fields is contrary to the notion of 'private'.`... but WHY???...

Answer (score 2):

Private fields can not be accessed dynamically.
One way to get dynamic private fields is with Symbols.

A symbol is a scalar, just like a string.
You create symbols like this:

```
let myXyzSymbol = Symbol('my_xyz_symbol');
// note the absence of `new`
```

A symbol is always unique. This means that following is always `false`:

```
Symbol('x') === Symbol('x')
```

Now, we have all the pieces to do something about dynamic privates.

Create a symbol and do not export it outside the module. This makes it private.

```
const mySym = Symbol('foo');


export class Something {

    [mySym]() {
        // This function can not be called by
        // a caller that does not have access to mySym.
    }

}
```

More on Symbols

- The `Symbol.for()` function is different from `Symbol()`, but both return a symbol.
- Check out the MDN docs for [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)
- And an [article here](https://mitya.uk/articles/using-symbols-private-properties)

Comment: +1. pretty much the only solution except putting all the privates in a private namespace, as the top-voted answer shows. And thanks for linking to my article.

Answer (score 1):

Private fields and methods **can be accessed dynamically**, if you have some fantasy!
So, you have **two private methods** in your class:

```
  #media(method) {
    return ({
      import: this.#import.bind(this),
    }[method](method))
  }
  
  #import(method) {
    alert(this.#media)
    return {method: '@' + method}
  }
```

In this case you can call #import like this:

```
this.#media('import')
```

**Note**, you should set the correct scope for #import with bind(this), if you want to use "this" as class pointer inside.